# Stack overflow when folding infinite lists?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold

Consider the following function:

```
(<.>) :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
xs <.> ys = zipWith (++) xs ys
```

This essentially takes two two-dimensional arrays of `a`s and concatanates them, left to right, e.x.:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]] <.> [[1,2],[3,4]] == [[1,2,1,2],[3,4,3,4]]
```

I would like to be able to write something like the following:

```
x = foldr1 (<.>) $ repeat [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Which should make sense due to Haskell's lazy evaluation, i.e. we should obtain:

```
x !! 0 == [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2...]
x !! 1 == [3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4...]
```

However, when I try to run this example with GHCi, either using `foldr1` or `foldl1`, I either get a non-terminating computation, or a stack overflow.

So my question is:

1. What's going on here?
2. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish here with some function other than `foldr1` or `foldl1`? (I'm happy if I need to modify the implementation of `<.>`, as long as it computes the same function)

Also, note: I'm aware that for this example, `map repeat [[1,2],[3,4]]` produces the desired output, but I am looking for a solution that works for arbitrary infinite lists, not just those of the form `repeat xs`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the point, could you maybe give a non-trivial example (i.e. not achievable with `map repeat . <.>`

Comment: The problem is that `zipWith` needs at least to evaluate the lists at the top level. Since the right parameter is another `zipWith` (and that keeps going on), you keep calling endlessly.

Comment: In short, you can only `fold` an infinite list here, if you can postpone the evaluation of the right element. But `zipWith` needs to evaluate both the two lists.

Comment: You might like `map concat . transpose $ repeat [[1,2],[3,4]]`. It at least satisfies your two equations... though you might run into trouble if you try to write down the obvious third equation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll expand on what's been said in the comments here. I'm going to borrow (a simplified version of) the [GHC version of `zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zipWith), which should suffice for the sake of this discussion.

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith f [] _ = []
zipWith f _ [] = []
zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith f xs ys
```

Now, here's what your computation ends up looking like, in it's glorious infinite form.

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]] <.> ([[1, 2], [3, 4]] <.> ([[1, 2], [3, 4]] ... ) ... )
```

Okay, so the top-level is a `<.>`. Fine. Let's take a closer look at that.

```
zipWith (++) [[1, 2], [3, 4]] ([[1, 2], [3, 4]] <.> ([[1, 2], [3, 4]] ... ) ... )
```

Still no problems yet. Now we look at the patterns for `zipWith`. The first pattern only matches if the left-hand-side is empty. Welp, that's definitely not true, so let's move on. The second only matches if the right-hand-side is empty. So let's see if the right-hand-side is empty. The right-hand-side looks like

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]] <.> ([[1, 2], [3, 4]] <.> ([[1, 2], [3, 4]] ... ) ... )
```

Which is what we started with. So to compute the result, we need access to the result. Hence, stack overflow.

Now, we've established that our problem is with `zipWith`. So let's play with it. First, we know we're going to be applying this to infinite lists for our contrived example, so we don't need that pesky empty list case. Get rid of it.

```
-- (I'm also changing the name so we don't conflict with the Prelude version)
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys

(<.>) :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
xs <.> ys = zipWith' (++) xs ys
```

But that fixes nothing. We still have to evaluate to weak head normal form (read: figure out of the list is empty) to match that pattern.

If only there was a way to do a pattern match without having to get to WHNF... enter [lazy patterns](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_pattern_match). Let's rewrite our function this way.

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f ~(x:xs) ~(y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

Now our function will *definitely* break if given a finite list. But this allows us to "pretend" pattern match on the lists without actually doing any work. It's equivalent to the more verbose

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f xs ys = f (head xs) (head ys) : zipWith' f (tail xs) (tail ys)
```

And now we can test your function properly.

```
*Main> let x = foldr1 (<.>) $ repeat [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
*Main> x !! 0
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,...]
*Main> x !! 1
[3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,...]
```

The obvious downside of this is that it will definitely fail on finite lists, so you have to have a different function for those.

```
*Main> [[1, 2], [3, 4]] <.> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1,2,1,2],[3,4,3,4],*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Comment: A helpful combinator I use in situations like this is `nonempty ~(x:xs) = x:xs`. It "asserts" that a list is nonempty, and allows it to be used a bit more lazily thus. I believe this will fix the problem: `foldr1 (\x y -> nonempty (x <.> y)) ...`

Comment: I'm actually quite curious what other "situations like this" you've encountered.

Comment: @luqui I have tried that, and it does work. (Another possibility in this case would be using `NonEmpty` for the middle layer.)

Answer (score 5):

`zipWith` is not -- in fact, it can't possibly be -- as lazy as you'd like. Consider this variation on your example:

```
GHCi> foldr1 (zipWith (++)) [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [] ]
[]
```

Any empty list of lists in the input will lead to an empty list of lists result. That being so, there is no way to know any of the elements of the result until the whole input has been consumed. Therefore, your function won't terminate on infinite lists.

[Silvio Mayolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56614916/2751851) goes through some potential workarounds for this issue. My suggestion is using non-empty-lists of lists, instead of plain lists of lists:

```
GHCi> import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as N
GHCi> import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..))
GHCi> take 10 . N.head $ foldr1 (N.zipWith (++)) $ repeat ([1,2] :| [[3,4]])
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

`N.zipWith` [doesn't have to deal with an empty list case](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.List.NonEmpty.html#zipWith), so it can be lazier.